# Trace MongoDB projections

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the official C# driver and working through some performance issues with large documents.  I can turn on profiling and see the query without a problem.  In addition, I can view the query via MongoQuery.ToString().  But what I'm after is the projection document created with SetFields().

The projection document doesn't seem to be included in profile doc. Is there any logging or tracing available in driver that may help?